# Accessing fields of a tfs work item after retrieving work items from query

Tags: javascript, tfs

I am trying to retrieve all bug work item types from a TFS server. I'm pretty sure I retrieved all the IDs of all the bug work items in the project but now I can't figure out how to get field values from those bug items.

```
VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformScripts: true,
            usePlatformStyles: true
        });

        VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"], function (VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {

                var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
                var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient)
                var query = {
                    query: "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' order by [System.CreatedDate] asc"
                };

                witClient.queryByWiql(query, projectId).then(
                    function (result) {

                        var openWorkItems = result.workItems.map(function (wi) { 
                            return wi.id; 
                        });

                        var fields = [
                            "System.Title",
                            "System.CreatedDate"
                        ];

                        witClient.getWorkItems(openWorkItems, fields).then(
                            function (workItems) {
                                //
                                //how do I retrieve workitem fields here
                                //
                            });
                    });
        });
```